# What does “like an elephant's eye” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, american-english

What does “**like an elephant's eye**” mean from "**We seldom ever have an argument, but if it is, it's about something like an elephant's eye**"? The sentence is from an interview, an old couple talks about their relationship. I googled, but can't find the meaning.

Thank you! :)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448780/as-high-as-an-elephants-eye

Comment: It's about something like a potato's eye or a tornado's eye.  "Like an elephant's eye" is not an idiom.  "Like", in this case, isn't being used to suggest a simile, but rather simply means "similar to".  The main implication is that it's about something that's unimportant and that the arguer knows very little about -- something not worth arguing about.

Comment: @lbf  I don't think "as high as an elephant's eye" is as same as "like an elephant's eye".

Comment: @Hot Licks Thank you! But I still can't understand the connection between "an elephant's eye" and "unimportant ".

Comment: How much do you know about an elephant's eye?  How important is that (lack of) knowledge to you, your family, and your friends?

Comment: *"We seldom ever have an argument, but **if it is**, it's about something like an elephant's eye"* - This sentence is not written by a native speaker. We would not say, "if it is", we would say "if we do". Where did you find this sentence?  (Note that "seldom ever" is also incorrect although some less well-educated natives might say it)

Comment: Hi @chasly from UK  Thank you! This is taken an interview with an old couple who is from Georgia, US. You can read the full interview transcript here: https://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=677760002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the use of a nonsence word.

> "We seldom ever have an argument, but if it is, it's about something
>   like an **elephant's eye**."

nonsense words [TFD](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Nonsense+word)

> words are used in literature for poetic or humorous  effect. Proper
>   names of real or fictional entities are sometimes  nonsense words.

The sentence could have been written:

> "We seldom ever have an argument, but if we do, it's about
>   the weather on mars!"

meaning

> "Our arguments were rare and were about nothing of significance."